# Find (latent) variables which correlate with age of samples (Time series correlations)

Tags: time-series, correlation, dataset, chemometrics

I have 8 samples of whisky which are all from the same producer, matured in the same type of casks. However, the casks were (naturally) different. 
My ages range from 5 years to 32 years old, but superficially the samples do not fit that trend. 
I.e. the sample variation is caused by cask variation more than age of sample.

I have a few spectroscopic techniques to hand to analyse these, for example mass spectrometry. This has produced for each sample circa ~ 2000 formula/variables and an associated relative abundance.

The question is: **Can I model the data against the known variable (age), and discover which, if any, of the variables fit with that?** If so, how?
Or are 8 samples simply too small a sample set?

For example, I tried calculating the R² for each variable of Age vs Variable, but with only 8 samples and >2000 variables, this doesnt seem statistically valid.

Any ideas appreciated.

---

p.s. for what its worth, i have two different sets of 8. I.e. 5-30 for one type of whisky, 5-30 for another type. But that only introduces more variation, surely.

Comment: How about modelling the age as a function of the >2000 variables with a sparse regression (e.g. lasso). You could see how much of the age was explained by the spectroscopic data.